# Java ArrayBlockingQueue design

Tags: java, collections

i just found while studying the JDK 1.6 `ArrayBlockingQueue` - The constructor makes a call to one of the public overridable methods ! I thought this is a bad practice specially for an API.

```
 public ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity, boolean fair,
                          Collection<? extends E> c) {
    this(capacity, fair);
    if (capacity < c.size())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    for (Iterator<? extends E> it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        add(it.next()); // -> surprise:  add is public 
}
```

I was actually trying to extend the `ArrayBlockingQueue` , and add some some state and overrided `add()` , and I promptly got the `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I invoked `super(capacity,fair,col)` constructor. Am I missing some design concept here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't so out of the ordinary; essentially, you can think of this as just a one-line syntax for the lines

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<E> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<E>(capacity, fair);
queue.addAll(c);
```

which is overridable.  Calling overridable methods isn't usually a good idea, but it's perfectly reasonable here.

But...that said, extending any collection from `java.util` or `java.util.concurrent` is kind of evil.  You should decorate them, rather than extending them directly.

Comment: The stuff I am doing has to do with ensuring synchronization .. to take a decorator approach means to have additional locks ( over and above the locks used internally by ABQ ) .. extending it can directly override the method and I can push my state changes into the same sync block

Comment: But then you take the risk of breaking the internal synchronization of an implementation which is core part of your framework. If you just need some extra state information and if correctly designed your implementation shouldn't become a bottleneck.

Comment: If you're concerned about duplicated synchronization, then just _reimplementing_ `ArrayBlockingQueue` isn't difficult at all.  Heck, write it as a decorator for `ArrayDeque`, managing the synchronization yourself.